# How to make a greater/less than or equal to on python?

Tags: python

So I just started studying programming today and I tried to make a code about guessing the number from 1 to 10. but when I input 0 or 11, it also shows the message for `guess > number` or `guess < number`.

Here's my code:

```
number = 4
running = True
while running:
    guess = int(input('Guess the number from 1 to 10 :'))

    if guess == number:
        print('Congrats, you guessed it right')
        running = False
    if guess > 10:
        print('Choose from only 1 to 10!, Please try again')
    if guess < 1:
        print('Choose from only 1 to 10, Please try again')
    if guess > number:
       print('Sorry, a little lower than that, Please try again')
    if guess < number:
        print('Sorry, a little higher than that, Please try again')
else:
    print('DONE!')
```

Here's the output:

```
Guess the number from 1 to 10 :0
Choose from only 1 to 10, Please try again
Sorry, a little higher than that, Please try again
Guess the number from 1 to 10 :11
Choose from only 1 to 10!, Please try again
Sorry, a little lower than that, Please try again
Guess the number from 1 to 10 :
```

as you can see, it also prints the message. I input for the `guess > number` or `guess < number` (on the 3rd and 6th line of the output). I noticed that the problem was that it should be greater than or equal to and less than or equal to, but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Hint: `else` or `elif` let you run only one branch of code.

Comment: Look into the use of  `elif`

Comment: `guess >= number`, `..<=..` ... [https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#value-comparisons](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#value-comparisons) .. https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#operators

Answer (score 1):

You could go for something like this:

```
number = 4
guess = -1
while guess != number: # When you find the number you exit the loop to print congrats.
    try:
        guess = int(input('Guess the number from 1 to 10 : '))
    except ValueError: # Catch the possible ValueError if the user doesn't supply a number.
        print('Enter a valid number!')
        continue

    if guess > 10 or guess < 1:
        print('Choose from only 1 to 10!, Please try again')
    elif guess > number: # Use elif in order not to print multiple messages.
        print('Sorry, a little lower than that, Please try again')
    elif guess < number:
        print('Sorry, a little higher than that, Please try again')

print('Congrats, you guessed it right')
```